# Command line wildcard matching tool with pipe support for Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, wildcards

I have not found any commandline tool which would print output only if it matches given wildcards. Wildcards * and ? needs to be supported.

For example

```
echo 192.168.1.1 | WildcardMatch "19?.168.*"
echo aa-02-23201 | WildcardMatch "*-??-232*"
```

Tried to implement this by using a batch file and calling PowerShell but this is way too slow. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/using-the-like-operator-and-wildcard-characters-in-string-comparisons-c472b6df-0d3e-4ffc-a21c-bb5721cc460a

Edit: -i is needed to make the match case-sensitive.

Comment: This feels like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What is it you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have files with thousand of lines and a filters containing ? and * characters and only matching lines should be processed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an examaple of how to use PowerShell which supports `?` and `*`.

https://github.com/Tataz2/likeSTR

PowerShell scripts can be compiled to exes.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

#### I have not found any command line tool which would print output only if it matches given wildcards.

> Wildcards * and ? needs to be supported.

There are no command line tools that support `?` as a rexexp character that I am aware of.

However you can use `findstr` to do the match you are looking for as follows:

This will match:

```
F:\test>echo 192.168.1.1 | findstr /r "[1][9][1-9].168.*"
192.168.1.1
```

This will not match:

```
F:\test>echo 182.168.1.1 | findstr /r "[1][9][1-9].168.*"

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Findstr - Search for strings - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html)
- [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also install [grep](https://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm) for Windows and use more or less basic regexes.

Examples based on yours, with Perl engine in use, but ou could switch to e.g. faster `-G` instead:

- less accurate IP match:

  `echo 192.168.1.1 | grep -P "19\d\.168\..*?"`
- more accurate IP match:

  `echo 192.168.1.1 | grep -P "19\d\.168\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}"`
- pattern match:

  `echo aa-02-23201 | grep -P "[a-z]{2}-\d{2}-232\d+"`